# How to block jenkins build till certain pipeline stage is finished

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have two builds:

- Build 1
- Pipeline Build 2 with stages: A -> B -> C

Is it possible to block Build 1 till stage B is finished?

Standard blocking plugin checks only names of other jobs.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it is to schedule both `Build 1` and stages `A` and `B` on some node with a unique label. This way, if the Build 2 is running and already using that node, Build 1 will be waiting in the queue on the node.

Another option to consider is using [Lockable Resources plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/).

Comment: So you think to base on blocked resources? Unfortunately I don't have many and I utilize what I can. Any other option ? 
Something like 'Build Blocker', but going deeper into a pipeline stages.